# Excel interop MissingMethodException on some systems

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

In my C# program, I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. With this i am reading & writing data to excel file. On one machine, even though it has Office 2007, there are seeing below exception, raises at GetComponentPath() method call.

Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Type System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetTypeFromCLSID(System.GUID)'.

Here is my code:

```
public static string GetComponentPath(OfficeComponent _component)
{
    string toReturn = string.Empty;
    string _key = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application _excelApp = null;
        _excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        if (_excelApp != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Excel is installed");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Excel not found.");
        }               
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error \n" + ex.ToString());
    }
    return toReturn;
}

public enum OfficeComponent
{
    Word,
    Excel,
    PowerPoint,
    Outlook
}
```

Comment: Which framework you are using?

Comment: I am using .net framwork 4.0 @user3588674

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** you have developed your application in your local machine with heigher version of `.NET Framework` and running the same on remote pc having Lower Version of`.NET Framework`.

Note : if you target your application to run on `Heigher` Version of `.NET Framework` it wont run on lower versions.

**Solution :** you need to target it to `.NET Framework` Lower Version available on your remote PC to run on remote pc.

**Step 1:**  right click on `project` - select `properties`

**Step 2:**  change the `Target Framework` from `.NET Framework  x.x` to `.NET Framework x.y`.

Note : where `x.x` is heigher and `x.y` is lower version available on remote pc or any lower version.

Comment: I have developed my application in .net framework 4.0 and it is necessary that other machine should also have 4.0 installed in it, otherwise application won't run. But on other system application is running but excel part is not working.

Comment: maybe this link will help you..http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-tutorial.htm